# Estrutura de dados que represente um baralho de cartas

Tags: python, python-3.x, estrutura-de-dados

Estou a desenvolver um projecto em Python, onde tenho que representar um jogo de cartas. Estou com dúvida em relação qual a melhor estrutura de dados a usar, segundo a descrição fornecida:

Cada carta deverá ser representada por um par (,), no qual ambos os elementos são strings. As faces possíveis são: ‘A’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ..., ‘10’, ‘J’, ‘Q’, ‘K’. Os naipes são: ‘O’, ‘P’,   ‘C’ e ‘E’.

Por exemplo:

- O Ás de espadas é representado pelo par (‘A’,’E’);
- A Dama de paus, pelo par (‘Q’,’P’);

Um baralho completo é uma lista das 52 cartas existentes. Uma mão é também uma  lista de cartas.
O jogo tem várias rondas, em    cada    ronda   é   utilizado   um  novo    baralho,    cuja    sequência   de  cartas  deverá  ser lida
de   um  ficheiro    ‘baralho_.txt’,  em  que          deverá  ser     substituído     pelo    número  da  ronda.
Onde a mão é o conjunto de duas cartas que um jogador tem num dado momento.
Sou novo no mundo de Python, não sei o qual mais adequado. O baralho poderia ser um dicionário mas depois não tenho como representar a mão.

Excerto do ficheiro do baralho:

```
10 C
8 C
A P
2 P
7 P
4 C
10 O
7 E
9 E
8 E
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma opção é utilizar [`collections.namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import product

Carta = namedtuple('Carta', ['face', 'naipe'])

faces = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'}
naipes = {'O', 'P', 'C', 'E'}

baralho = [Carta(face, naipe) for face, naipe in product(faces, naipes)]

print('Seu baralho possui', len(baralho), 'cartas')
# Seu baralho possui 52 cartas
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/gsJciu) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HeftyIndianredVelvetworm)</sup>

Para gerar todas as cartas do baralho, utilizei a função [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Assim, para cada carta do baralho você pode fazer, por exemplo:

```
carta = baralho[0]
print(carta.face, carta.naipe)
```

Exibindo a face e a naipe da respectiva carta.

Para sortear aleatoriamente duas cartas para um jogador, você pode utilizar a função [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from random import sample

mao = sample(baralho, 2)

print('Mão do jogador:', mao)
# Mão do jogador: [Carta(face='Q', naipe='O'), Carta(face='A', naipe='P')]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ssrm3B) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MindlessAgreeableHapuka)</sup>

---

Dadas as novas informações sobre o baralho ficar armazenado em um arquivo, a lógica não se difere muito, apenas, ao invés de gerar todas as cartas possíveis, lê-las do respectivo arquivo. Supondo que o arquivo possui o nome de `baralho1.txt`, a definição do baralho seria algo parecido com:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Carta = namedtuple('Carta', ['face', 'naipe'])

baralho = []
with open('baralho1.txt') as ficheiro:
    for linha in ficheiro:
        carta = linha.strip().split()
        baralho.append(Carta(*carta))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MonthlyPinkMolly)</sup>

Assim, o objeto `baralho` será uma lista de tuplas `Carta` seguindo os valores que estavam armazenados no arquivo. Para o trecho do arquivo dado na pergunta, o resultado de `print(baralho)` seria:

```
[
  Carta(face='10', naipe='C'),
  Carta(face='8', naipe='C'),
  Carta(face='A', naipe='P'),
  Carta(face='2', naipe='P'),
  Carta(face='7', naipe='P'),
  Carta(face='4', naipe='C'),
  Carta(face='10', naipe='O'),
  Carta(face='7', naipe='E'),
  Carta(face='9', naipe='E'),
  Carta(face='8', naipe='E')
]
```

Você pode embaralhar as cartas através da função `random.shuffle`:

```
random.shuffle(baralho)
```

E depois, você poderia, por exemplo, distribuir a carta entre quatro jogadores:

```
jogador_a = baralho[0:2]
jogador_b = baralho[2:4]
jogador_c = baralho[4:6]
jogador_d = baralho[6:8]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HandmadeTruthfulLabradorretriever)</sup>

Ficando cada um com 2 cartas distintas. Obviamente que o processo de distribuir as cartas pode ser modificado conforme sua necessidade e até mesmo a forma de representar o jogador, caso existam outros requisitos a serem satisfeitos.

Comment: editei o posto, esqueci me de referir que o baralho é carregado a partir de um ficheiro a cada ronda. A mão que definiste é de que tipo?

Comment: @alves Ficheiro? E qual seria o conteúdo dele? De qualquer forma, acredito que com o que eu coloquei na resposta você já consiga fazer.

Comment: É um .txt com a face e o naipe, um em cada linha
Exemplo:
Q 0
A P

Comment: @alves coloque **na pergunta** um trecho deste ficheiro, por favor.

Comment: Editei o post com um excerto de um ficheiro.

Comment: @alves adicionei à resposta um exemplo de como poderia ser lendo a partir do ficheiro. Acredito que a partir disso você consegue fazer sozinho.

Comment: Entendi a resposta, obrigado pela ajuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito que eu encontrei foi fazer apenas uma lista com o valor das cartas assim:

```
baralho = ['A♥', 'K♥', 'Q♥', 'J♥', 'T♥', '9♥', '8♥', '7♥', '6♥', '5♥', '4♥','3♥', '2♥','A♠', 'K♠', 'Q♠', 'J♠', 'T♠','9♠', '8♠', '7♠', '6♠', '5♠', '4♠', '3♠', '2♠','A♦','K♦','Q♦', 'J♦', 'T♦', '9♦', '8♦', '7♦', '6♦', '5♦', '4♦', '3♦', '2♦', 'A♣', 'K♣', 'Q♣', 'J♣', 'T♣', '9♣', '8♣', '7♣', '6♣', '5♣', '4♣', '3♣', '2♣']
```

Fácil de manusear;
Pode se usar um `random.shuffle()` para embaralhar...
Obs: Pode se substituir os emojis pelo O P C E, Ouros, Paus...
T = 10