# Ordenando cartas em Python

Tags: python, lista, classificação, dicionário

Tenho uma lista com as cartas e o naipe de um baralho que preciso ordenar. Considerando a ordem correta:
A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K
E os naipes: P(paus). O(ouro), E(espada), C(copas)
Após a leitura do arquivo com todos as cartas de todos os naipes, preciso ordenar cada naipe.
Por exemplo: a leitura do arquivo retorna (vou considerar apenas um naipe):

```
K P
A P
3 P 
9 P
10 P
J P
4 P
2 P
6 P
8 P
7 P
Q P
5 P
```

Preciso ordenar pelo valor das cartas. Pensei em jogar em um dicionário onde as chaves são as cartas e o valor é o naipe, e depois ordenar pela chave, mas não consigo sair disso.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Meu código até agora:

```
arquivo = open('nome_arquivo.txt', 'r')
dados = arquivo.readlines()
dic = {}
for linha in dados:
    linha = linha.split()
    dic[linha[0]] = linha[1]
print(dic)
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Estrutura de dados que represente um baralho de cartas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261210/5878)

Comment: Se você jogar as cartas como chaves e os valores sendo os naipes, você vai ter (se estiver trabalhando com todas as cartas), quatro casos para cada chave.
Acredito que isso traria um problema para o resto do código.

No entanto, você poderia usar [listas aninhadas](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460) sendo a primeira posição o valor da carta e o segundo valor o naipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método “sorted” retorna a lista baralho ordenada de forma ascendente.

O método “enumerate” retorna o índice e os elementos da lista baralho.

As variáveis "k" e "v" recebem o índice e o elemento da lista baralho.

O método “strip” remove da “string” as quebras de linha, espaços em branco, etc.

O método “dic.update” atualiza o dicionário, a chave será a variável “k” e “v” o valor.

O método “dic.get” retorna o valor de uma chave especificada ou vazio se a chave não existir.

```
arquivo = open('cartas.txt', 'r')
baralho = arquivo.readlines()

dic = {}

for k, v in enumerate(sorted(baralho)):    
    v = v.strip().strip('\n').strip('P')
    dic.update({k:v})

if dic.get(0) != 'A':
    dic.update({0:'A'})

if dic.get(9) != '10':
    dic.update({9:'10'})

if dic.get(11) != 'Q':
    dic.update({11:'Q'})

if dic.get(12) != 'K':
    dic.update({12:'K'})

print(dic)
```

Comment: Saudações Éder. Considere também, junto com o código, adicionar uma explicação em texto do que implementou, como funciona e porque isso resolve o problema em questão. Vi que suas últimas respostas são basicamente código e isso dificilmente colaborá de alguma forma para a comunidade (e está sujeito a receber votos negativos). Lembre-se que um código pode ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários não.