# Como distribuir cartas de um baralho usando dicionário

Tags: python, lista, lógica

Tenho o seguinte dicionário composto por uma lista em seus valores:

```
baralho = { 'Paus':   ['Ás',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Dama','Valete','Reis'] ,
            'Ouros':  ['Ás',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Dama','Valete','Reis'] ,
            'Espadas':['Ás',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Dama','Valete','Reis'] ,
            'Copas':  ['Ás',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Dama','Valete','Reis'] }
```

Gostaria de saber como percorrer estas chaves e seus valores de forma sequencial e aleatória, sorteando 5 cartas. Sem lançar mão de funções do Python. Não sei como indexar os valores para cada chave.

Tentei por uma etapa mais simples:

```
for b in baralho:
   print(b)
```

O resultado foi a impressão apenas das chaves, tentei um `cont=0` e ir somando a cada loop para o índice mas deu o erro:  O objeto 'NoneType' não é subscritível.

```
 for b in baralho:
     print(b)[cont]     
     cont = cont + 1
```

Pesquisei aqui na plataforma mas não encontrei algo equivalente a esse problema, pode ser que eu não tenha utilizado de algum termo necessário.

Answer (score 3):

Não posso afirmar que seja o método ideal, pois são diversas maneiras que pode compreender as cartas de um baralho.
Mas uma forma simples de modelar cartas de um baralho é primeiro modelar os naipes, então modelar os valores e a partir desses formar as carta em baralho.

Para modelar os naipes e os valores das cartas pode-se usar [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) pois trata-se de um sequencia imutável, depois de definidos os valores não há o porque os alterar.

Para modelar uma única carta também use uma tupla pois criada a carta não há o porque alterar o seu valor.

Já para o baralho use uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) pois trata-se de um sequencia mutável e é interessante mudar a ordem dos elementos assim como adicionar e remover cartas.

Exemplo1: *Modelando o baralho e exibindo as suas cartas*.

```
naipes = ('Paus', 'Ouros', 'Espadas', 'Copas')

valores = ('A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,'Dama', 'Valete', 'Reis')

baralho = [(v, n) for v in valores for n in naipes]

for carta in baralho:
  print(carta)
```

Resultado:

```
('A', 'Paus')
('A', 'Ouros')
('A', 'Espadas')
('A', 'Copas')
(2, 'Paus')
(2, 'Ouros')
(2, 'Espadas')
(2, 'Copas')
(3, 'Paus')
(3, 'Ouros')
(3, 'Espadas')
(3, 'Copas')
(4, 'Paus')
(4, 'Ouros')
(4, 'Espadas')
(4, 'Copas')
(5, 'Paus')
(5, 'Ouros')
(5, 'Espadas')
(5, 'Copas')
(6, 'Paus')
(6, 'Ouros')
(6, 'Espadas')
(6, 'Copas')
(7, 'Paus')
(7, 'Ouros')
(7, 'Espadas')
(7, 'Copas')
(8, 'Paus')
(8, 'Ouros')
(8, 'Espadas')
(8, 'Copas')
(9, 'Paus')
(9, 'Ouros')
(9, 'Espadas')
(9, 'Copas')
(10, 'Paus')
(10, 'Ouros')
(10, 'Espadas')
(10, 'Copas')
('Dama', 'Paus')
('Dama', 'Ouros')
('Dama', 'Espadas')
('Dama', 'Copas')
('Valete', 'Paus')
('Valete', 'Ouros')
('Valete', 'Espadas')
('Valete', 'Copas')
('Reis', 'Paus')
('Reis', 'Ouros')
('Reis', 'Espadas')
('Reis', 'Copas')
```

Para embaralhar uma sequencia pode ser utilizado a função [`shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) do módulo nativo [`random`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/random.html).

Exemplo2: *Embaralhando as suas cartas*.

```
import random

naipes = ('Paus', 'Ouros', 'Espadas', 'Copas')

valores = ('A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,'Dama', 'Valete', 'Reis')

baralho = [(v, n) for v in valores for n in naipes]

random.shuffle(baralho)

for carta in baralho:
  print(carta)
```

Resultado:

```
(2, 'Paus')
('Valete', 'Ouros')
(3, 'Ouros')
('Reis', 'Copas')
(5, 'Paus')
('Reis', 'Paus')
(6, 'Ouros')
(9, 'Copas')
(6, 'Espadas')
(4, 'Copas')
(9, 'Espadas')
(2, 'Espadas')
(6, 'Paus')
(9, 'Ouros')
(7, 'Copas')
('Valete', 'Copas')
(3, 'Paus')
('A', 'Espadas')
('A', 'Paus')
(2, 'Copas')
(8, 'Copas')
(10, 'Espadas')
(4, 'Paus')
('A', 'Ouros')
(8, 'Ouros')
(5, 'Ouros')
('Dama', 'Paus')
(7, 'Ouros')
('Valete', 'Espadas')
(9, 'Paus')
(7, 'Paus')
(2, 'Ouros')
(5, 'Copas')
(6, 'Copas')
(10, 'Paus')
('Reis', 'Espadas')
(10, 'Copas')
('Valete', 'Paus')
(4, 'Espadas')
('Dama', 'Espadas')
('Reis', 'Ouros')
(10, 'Ouros')
('Dama', 'Ouros')
(7, 'Espadas')
(3, 'Espadas')
(8, 'Espadas')
(3, 'Copas')
(4, 'Ouros')
('Dama', 'Copas')
(5, 'Espadas')
(8, 'Paus')
('A', 'Copas')
```

Como um teste para o modelo e exemplo de como **sortear n cartas** pode ser criado um jogo de 21 onde o jogador só ganha se fizer exatamente 21 pontos.

O jogo começa limpando o monte de cartas do jogado e em seguida embaralha-se o baralho.
Com o método [list.pop()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) é retirada uma carta do baralho e adicionada ao monte do jogador. O valor da carta é computado e somado aos pontos do usuário.

Os pontos são computados segundo essa tabela:

| Carta | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 Se a total de pontos for maior que 10 |
| A | 11 Se a total de pontos for menores que 10 |
| 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | Tem como valor o próprio valor de face |
| Dama | Vale 12 pontos |
| Valete | Vale 13 pontos |
| Rei | Vale 14 pontos |

Se o jogador abandonar a mão com menos de 21 pontos ou se fizer mais de 21 pontos ele perde.
Ganha se somente se fizer exatos 21 pontos.

Exemplo3: *Jogo de 21*

```
import random

naipes = ('Paus', 'Ouros', 'Espadas', 'Copas')

valores = ('A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,'Dama', 'Valete', 'Reis')

#Função para lipar a tela.
cls = lambda: print("\033c\033[3J", end='')

#Função para gerar um novo baralho.
def embaralhar():
  b = [(v, n) for v in valores for n in naipes]
  random.shuffle(b)
  return b

#Função para computar o valor da carta.
def calcular(pontos, carta):
  if carta[0] == 'A':
    return 11 if pontos <= 10 else 1
  if carta[0] in ('Dama', 'Valete', 'Reis'):
    return (
      12 if carta[0] == 'Dama' else
      13 if carta[0] == 'Valete' else
      14
    )
  return int(carta[0])

vitorias = 0        #Numeros de vitórias 
derrotas = 0        #Numeros de derrotas 

frase1 = "Bem vindo a jogatina."
frase2 = "Deseja jogar uma partida?(S/N)"
frase3 = "Puxar mais uma carta?(S/N)"
frase4 = "Você venceu."
frase5 = "Você perdeu."
frase6 = "Pressione <Enter> para continuar..."


print(frase1)
while((jogar:= input(frase2).upper()) == "S" ):
  cls()                       #Limpa a tela.
  monte = []                  #Limpa o monte do jogador
  baralho = embaralhar()      #Inicializa um novo baralho, já embaralhado.
  soma = 0                    #Inicializa os pontos do jogador.
  while(True):
    cls()                                      #Limpa a tela.
    monte.append(carta:= baralho.pop())        #Tira uma  carta do baralho e adiciona ao monte
    soma += calcular(soma, carta)              #Calcula o valor da carta e soma aos pontos do jogador.
    #Imprime o placar do jogo
    print(f'Vitorias: {vitorias}\tDerrotas: {derrotas}')
    print(*monte, sep="\n", end="")
    print(f'\ttotal: {soma}')
    #Testa condições de saída da mão. 
    if (soma >= 21) or input(frase3).upper() != "S":      
      break    
  #Testa vitória ou derrota.
  if (soma == 21):
      print(frase4)
      vitorias += 1
  else:
      print(frase5)
      derrotas += 1
  input(frase6)
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/21#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação @Augusto, compreendi melhor sendo explicado por partes como vc fez. Implementei aqui conforme adaptações e deu certo de listar as cartas, agora irei trabalhar para randomizar a escolha das 5 cartas, valeu!

Comment: @CarlosM.Santos, com assim. Veja no segundo exemplo que depois de `random.shuffle(baralho)` basta apenas pegar cinco cartas ou do começo ou do fim da lista, que o resultado é sempre aleatório.

Comment: @CarlosM.Santos Adicionei um terceiro exemplo mostrando como sortear n cartas.

Comment: Já que já respondeu... seria duplicada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261210/5878

Comment: @Woss, sendo sincero acredito que seja uma duplicada. Muito boa reposta por sinal(Já havia nela votado em 2019 eu acho)

Comment: @Augusto boa noite! sua resposta me ajudou a compreender a lógica do jogo de baralho e foi além, deu um exemplo excelente de um jogo completo. No caso da pergunta deste tópico, eu precisava fazer a distribuição de cartas utilizando especificamente o conceito de dicionários e listas da forma que eu apresentei. Compreendo que possa parecer desnecessário ir por este caminho mas a proposta é saber lidar com a estrutura em questão (dicionário contendo uma lista dentro dela). Fico muito grato!

Answer (score 1):

Para listar todas as cartas em sequência:

```
def lista_cartas(baralho):
lista = []
for naipe in baralho:
    for carta in baralho[naipe]:
        lista.append(carta)
return lista

print(lista_cartas(baralho))
```

Para escolher 5 Cartas Aleatórias:

```
import random

def escolhe_carta(baralho):
lista_escolhidas = []
naipe = random.choice(list(baralho.keys()))
carta = random.choice(baralho[naipe])
lista_escolhidas.append([naipe, carta])
return lista_escolhidas

for i in range(5):
    for i in escolhe_carta(baralho):
        print(f'Naipe: {i[0]} \nCarta: {i[1]}')
        print('-' * 20)
```